# How to prove feasibility?

Tags: linear-programming

Let's say I have a optimization problem P1, where the constraints are linear but the objective function is not. Let's say I have another optimization problem which is linear in constraints and linear in the objective function.

The goal of the problem is to show that if P1 has a bounded optimum value then P2 has the same optimum value.

Now we want to prove two things to achieve that.

1. Prove that for every feasible solution $x$ of P1, there is a feasible solution $y$ of P2 with f(x) = g(y)
2. Prove that for every feasible solution $y$ of P2, there is a feasible solution $x$ of Pq with f(x) = g(y)

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a difference between the proofs of the two statements above?
2. How do I go about proving that for every feasibile solution of P1 there is a feasible solution for P2 and vice versa? I am looking for a high level template or a series of steps to achieve this, nothing specific.

Comment: There are obviously things that you don't tell us in your question, or I completely misunderstand it. Two problems have the same feasible solutions iff the constraints are equivalent (linear or not). Two distinct objective functions (linear or not) have no reason to have the same optimum.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're right I have left out specific details regarding the question. So would it suffice to show just that the constraints are equivalent/the same for P1 and P2?

Comment: To prove what ??

Comment: To prove that for every feasible solution x of P1, there is a feasible solution y of P2 with f(x) = g(y).

Comment: Why would that be true ???

Answer (score 3):

The theorems are true iff the images of the feasible sets by their respective function coincide (whatever the kind of constraints and kind of functions). This has no reason to occur in general.

One of the theorems can hold accidentally if one of the images is a subset of the other. For instance if the P2 function is such that it reaches the minimum and maximum of the P1 function, the first theorem holds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a P1 where the values of the objective function are constrained.

```
P1
Objective: max f(x) = Sin(x)
Constraints: 0 <= x <= 10

P2
Objective: max g(x) = x
Constraints: 0 <= x <= 10
```

It should be obvious that in this case, 1. holds but 2. does not.

A proof could look like that:

For 1.:
`0 <= x <= 10`  implies `min(g(x)) = 0 <= min(f(x)) = 0` and `max(g(x)) = 1 <= max(f(x)) = 10` therefore (with Intermediate value theorem which lets us know all values between the min and max are reached) 1.

For $\neg$ 2.:
`0 <= x <= 10`  implies `max(f(x)) = 10 > max(g(x)) = 1`, so 2. is not true since there is no feasible solution with g(x) = 10.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I expressed it badly, the feasible area is convex. The important part here is to somehow get to the information that all values in between the minimun and maximum are reached. That's the case IIRC if the function is continuous and the domain is convex. (Intermediate value theorem, Wikipedia only has a 1-D case but I am reasonably sure a n-D generalization would need convexity of the domain, but maybe connectedness would also be enough)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I honestly completely misunderstood the question, I thought the constraints were the same. If the two domains share no point, you can still argue with the maximum and minimum values, I don't see where my proof would actually require the domains to be the same.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I removed the "convexity" part and just directly referred to Intermediate value theorem, I think I am better off with that because in the end that is what I mean.

Comment: Nothing is said about the constraints and the functions (not even continuity !), the question is very ill-formulated.  But you are right, my bad, all that matters is the overlap between the images by f and g and the codomains play no role, this is a pure 1D question.